# Is there a generic Stack Exchange site for questions that don't fit in specific Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I love the Stack Exchange network and generally prefer it over Quora, Yahoo Answers and other Q&A sites. Occasionally I may have a question that won't correspond subject areas of any of the existing Stack Exchange network sites. Is there a Stack Exchange site for questions like that?

Comment: *Why* do you generally prefer Stack Exchange over Quora / Yahoo Answers? Therein lies your answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have a new topic to suggest, you can always go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/ to suggest it. As long as you clearly define the scope of the site, and keeps Stack Exchange's general concepts regarding a good Q&A in mind.

Comment: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com

Comment: As others have said, if the question is not on-topic at any stack, then, no, there's nowhere to ask. But if you're not sure if your question is on-topic somewhere, or you're pretty sure it is on-topic at some stack, but you're not sure which one, then you can ask for guidance about which stack to use here, on MSE, using the [tag:site-recommendation] tag.

Comment: @bjb568 With enough imagination you could also use Worldbuilding. Just pretend the problem you are facing is happening to a character in a story you are writting :P

Answer (score 10):

No. That's what sets Stack Exchange apart from Quora / YA etc - the sites are specifically focussed so that you get expert answers.

Just look at all the guff / trolling / nonsense that you get on those sites.

Also, are you sure there isn't a corresponding Stack Exchange site for your questions? [There are many, many sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) ranging from video games, cycling, physics, boardgames, Judaism and beyond. Surely there's one to fit your question?

Comment: Unless your question is about CAD. Or blacksmithing. *shakes fist*

Comment: @JasonC Ah. Well at least you tried!

Answer (score 8):

No, there isn't. No idea what that would look like and why anyone would bother to go there.

What we do have, however, is a site where you can suggest new sites and topics - if your suggestion gets enough community backing, it will get a chance to become a Stack Exchange site - see [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).